# Bulk file upload into Azure Media Services not finishing

Tags: azure-media-services

When trying to bulk upload a file to Azure Media Services using an IngestManifest the Asset is created, IngestionManifest blob container is also created and the process gets into the stage when the file appears to be fully in both the Manifest and Asset blob containers but the Asset is marked as empty, of 0 size and the Ingestion Manifest with the 1 file pending and 0 finished indefinitely. This is happening in the same way when ingesting a file (MP4 to test) with our own code using the .Net AMS SDK but also  with the AMS Explorer tool. The AMS account is a new account also with a new V2 storage as primary account behind it, so it more likely to be in some configuration or settings I would think, but otherwise a complete mystery.

Answer (score 0):

This was an error behaviour and was resolved by Microsoft.